# Microsoft Word (macOS) missing Paste Special and therefore unable to paste with formatting

Tags: macos, ms-office, copy-paste

I'm unable to paste with formatting on my Word Documents and for some strange reason, Paste Special only has an option for unformatted text. I've attached screenshots to explain further. [image: Image to explain the problem]

Comment: Which version of Word, and what version of MacOS?

Comment: I'm using Word 16.81 and MAC OS SONOMA 14.3

Comment: What is the file format? Do you get this behavior with a new .docx file in freshly re-started Word? Over here, Word 16.81, Sonoma 14.3, the Paste button at the left end of the Home toolbar has options for "Keep Source Formatting", "Match Formatting", "Paste as Picture", and "Keep Text Only", plus "Paste Special..." which offers 6 options, one of which is "Unformatted Text" as your picture shows. It seems to me this is happening due to something about the source you're copying from, so that Word has only unformatted text in its clipboard. Or maybe something external: a rogue clipboard manager?

Comment: Hey Bruce! You were right. I changed some settings on my Clipboard Manager and the options miraculously came back. Thanks!!!

Comment: Sweet! Probably a good idea to add a note to your question or post your own answer, for the benefit of future Ask Diff searchers.